# Understanding of rpm commands(-ivh vs -uvh)

Tags: fedora, rpm

Just want to know how different `rpm -ivh <packagename>` is from `rpm -uvh <packagename>`.

Comment: Did you check out the `man` pages?

Answer (score 1):

From the man page:

```
   The general form of an rpm install command is

   rpm {-i|--install} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...

   This installs a new package.

   The general form of an rpm upgrade command is

   rpm {-U|--upgrade} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...

   This  upgrades  or  installs the package currently installed to a newer
   version.  This is the same as install, except all other  version(s)  of
   the package are removed after the new package is installed.
```

Comment: As far as I know -ivh checks the dependencies along the installation. I am just curious about -ivh and -uvh. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- RPM always checks dependencies prior to any operations, except when you instruct it not to, e.g. by using flags like `--force` or `--nodeps`.
- There's **no** `-u` invocation, there's a capital `-U`.
- `-i` instructs RPM to install a package which is not yet installed on the system and it will fail if a package with the same name is already installed
- `-U` instructs RPM to update a package which is already installed on the system and it will fail if no package with the same name and lesser version is already installed.

RPM is always safe to use (sans `--nodeps` and `--force`) unlike `dpkg`.

Comment: Thx Artem quite a good explanation. Can you descrive vh?

Comment: There's a man page for that, `-v, --verbose
              Print verbose information - normally routine progress messages will be displayed.`  `-h, --hash
              Print 50 hash marks as the package archive is unpacked.  Use with -v|--verbose for a nicer display.`